# Saving a new list from a a larger list using a loop

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I have a large list, which I am pulling out every nth value from the first value up to the mth value to create new lists and I am using a for loop. My question is, how do I create a new list variable each time through the for loop?

By way of simple example, I have the list:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
```

Which I am trying to convert to:

```
a1 = [1,1,1]
...
a4 = [4,4,4]
```

As a printed output I get what I want when I run the code

```
split = list(range(0,3))

for x in split:
   a_new = a[x::3]
   print(a_new)
```

But like I say, I want to be able to use those lists later. (I want to use the lists as columns for a dataframe).

**Alternatively** If there is a more elegant way to simply convert my original list to a pandas data frame with a1 being one column, a2 being the next column and so on, that would also be great.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to use it as a column for a dataframe is there any issue with building the data iteratively as you split the list?

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I don’t expect there would be, but I am unsure how to do so. Would it be straightforward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary in the for loop then convert it to a dataframe.

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

a=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]

d = {}
for x in range(4):
   d['a'+str(x+1)] = a[x::4]
   
print(d, '\n')

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output

```
{'a1': [1, 1, 1], 'a2': [2, 2, 2], 'a3': [3, 3, 3], 'a4': [4, 4, 4]}

 a1  a2  a3  a4
  1   2   3   4
  1   2   3   4
  1   2   3   4
```

Comment: This is great @Mike67. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

If len(a) is divisble by n, then:

```
n = 3
m = 4

a = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]

pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(a, (n, m)), columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

    a   b   c   d
    1   2   3   4
    1   2   3   4
    1   2   3   4
```

Comment: no problem, obviously add column names in a better way, like [f'c{i}' for i in range(m)]